# how do I fix my program that "slows down" windows clock time?

Tags: c++, windows, time, clock

I asked a similar question recently, however none of the responses ended up working. The main difference now is that I have the logic for the program yet I still don't know why the clock runs faster than expected.
Anyway, I have a program that should slow down the speed of the windows clock by whatever percent I request. For some reason, it appears to make the clock run faster than I expected and I can't figure out why. The issue doesn't appear to be in the logic, as I've tested it with a large variety of numbers. I believe the issue lies in the optimization but I could be wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sysinfoapi.h>

int main() {
    int timeFactor;
    SYSTEMTIME lt;

    std::cout << "Enter a number 1-100: ";
    std::cin >> timeFactor;

    GetLocalTime(&lt);
    long timeBefore = lt.wMilliseconds;//975
    while (true) {
        Sleep(100);
        GetLocalTime(&lt);//025
        long SC = lt.wMilliseconds;
        long timeDifference = lt.wMilliseconds - timeBefore;//-950

        if (timeDifference < 0)
        {
            long timeToSet = ((timeFactor / 100.0f) * (((timeBefore -1000) * -1) + SC)) + timeBefore;//1000
            if (timeToSet >= 1000)
            {
                timeToSet -= 1000;
                lt.wMilliseconds = timeToSet;
            }else
            {
                lt.wMilliseconds = timeToSet;
                lt.wSecond -= 1;
            }
        }else
        {
            long timeToSet = ((timeFactor / 100.0f) * timeDifference) + timeBefore;
            lt.wMilliseconds = timeToSet;
        }
        SetLocalTime(&lt);

        printf("The time is: %02d:%02d:%02d.%02d\n", lt.wHour, lt.wMinute, lt.wSecond, lt.wMilliseconds);
        
        GetLocalTime(&lt);
        timeBefore = lt.wMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference to your previous question?

Comment: @ThomasSablik The main difference is that I figured out the logic for the program, but now I still don't know why the clock runs fast.

Comment: @Pow3rLine Did you read the [documentation on SetLocalTime?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setlocaltime).  Especially this -- *Therefore, to ensure the correct result, call SetLocalTime a second time, now that the first call has updated the daylight saving time setting.* -- In addition, did you check to see if `SetLocalTime` returns an error, and if so, call `GetLastError`?

Comment: I'm going to take some time to read it calmly, but I noticed that you took some measurements on more than one line (SC) and used them as the same, which is already an imbalance, reading about Windows Sleep and about time in general is said that the time varies up or down, maybe it needs some compensations

Comment: *>>why the clock runs faster than expected.* I saw same problem on virtual guest windows machine (KB 1005953). Probably it is hardware clock error.